# Mapping a vector of one type to another using lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming

I have a bit of code that looks like

```
B Convert(const A& a) { 
  B b;
  // implementation omitted.
  return b;
}

vector<B> Convert(const vector<A>& to_convert) {
  vector<B> ret;
  for (const A& a : to_convert) {
    ret.push_back(Convert(a));
  }
  retun ret;
}
```

I was trying to rewrite this using lambdas but the code does not look more concise or more clear at all:

```
vector<B> Convert(const vector<A>& to_convert) {
  vector<B> ret;
  std::transform(to_convert.begin(), 
                 to_convert.end(),
                 std::back_inserter(ret),
                 [](const A& a) -> B { return Convert(a); });
  retun ret;
}
```

What I would really like to do is something like:

```
vector<B> Convert(const vector<A>& to_convert) {
  return map(to_convert, [](const A& a) -> B { return Convert(a); });
}
```

Where `map` is a functional style map function that could be implemented as:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
vector<T2> map(const vector<T1>& to_convert, 
               std::function<T2(const T1&)> converter) {
  vector<T2> ret;
  std::transform(to_convert.begin(), 
                 to_convert.end(),
                 std::back_inserter(ret),
                 converter);
  retun ret;
}
```

Obviously the above is limited because it only works with `vector`, ideally one would want similar functions for all container types. At the end of the day, the above is still not better than my original code.

Why isn't there something like this (that I could find) in the stl?

Comment: Nope, not in the STL.  Or `std` for that matter.

Comment: Why is that? The existing methods that use iterators are so clunky and verbose.

Comment: decoupling of containers from iteration, and lack of concepts, which make container-based overloading easy.

Comment: Your code using `transform` is broken because passing `ret.begin()` from an empty `vector` will cause `transform` to write beyond the bounds. You need `std::back_inserter(ret)` as the 3rd argument.

Comment: @Praetorian thanks, I didn't actually test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it yourself, this `map` is not generic enough. `std::transform` on the other hand *is*, at the cost of more verbose interface. Another reason is that `map`, unlike `std::transform` forces new allocation, which is not always desirable.

Comment: Good point. I guess there is a limit to what you can do with lambda in C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class F, class R, class Out>
struct convert_t {
  F f;
  R r;
  // TODO: upgrade std::begin calls with Koenig lookup
  template<class D>
  operator D()&&{
    D d;
    std::transform(
      std::begin(std::forward<R>(r)),
      std::end(std::forward<R>(r)),
      std::back_inserter(d),
      std::forward<F>(f)
    );
    return d;
  }
  template<template<class...>class Z, class Result=Z<
    typename std::decay<Out>::type
  >>
  Result to()&&{return std::move(*this);}
};
template<class F, class R,
    class dF=typename std::decay<F>::type,
    class dR=typename std::decay<R>::type,
    class R_T=decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<dR>())),
    class Out=typename std::result_of<dF&(R_T)>::type
>
convert_t<dF,dR,Out>
convert( F&& f, R&& r ) { return {std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<R>(r)}; }
```

which gives us this:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3};
auto r = convert(Convert, vec).to<std::vector>();
for (auto&& x:r)
    std::cout << x << '\n';
std::vector<double> r2 = convert(Convert, vec);
for (auto&& x:r)
    std::cout << x << '\n';
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/966aef7057e4b1e5).

This only handles sequence container output, as `std::back_inserter` would have to be swapped for `std::inserter` or somesuch for associative containers.

Also, some associative containers (like `map`) don't like being passed a `pair` -- they want `Key,Value`.  Expressing that generically is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library takes care to separate containers, and their traversal. By having `std` algorithms take containers directly, you'd lose the possibility of using different iterator types for different methods of traversal.

For example, Boost.Iterator uses specifically this clean separation to provide a neat collection of every traversal method you could dream of.

Note also that not all iterators traverse actual containers : `std::back_inserter` (which you should use instead of `ret.begin()` if you don't want to fall into unallocated space) actually constructs the container as it goes, and `std::ostream_iterator` is completely unrelated to any container as it pushes what's assigned to it to a stream.

Of course, nothing stops you from making a thin wrapper for the classic begin/end traversal :

```
template <
    template <class...> class Container,
    class Transform,
    class ContainerT,
    class... ContainerParams
>
auto map(Container<ContainerT, ContainerParams...> const &container, Transform &&transform) {
    using DestT = std::result_of_t<Transform(ContainerT const&)>;
    Container<DestT, ContainerParams...> res;

    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    std::transform(
        begin(container),
        end(container),
        std::inserter(res, end(res)),
        std::forward<Transform>(transform)
    );

    return res;
}
```

[(live on Coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9023ee1e4441dc23)

Comment: Heads up that I tried this with clang++ v 14.0.0 and g++ 11.2.0 using -std=c++20, c++17, c++14 and in each case i got a static_assert error on the creation of 'res': "std::vector must have the same value_type as its allocator".  Looks like Coliru is using g++ version 12.1.0.

Comment: @thenumbernine hmm, that's pretty bad. Indeed my code replaces the element type but does not adjust the allocator type. I'm not sure how I could do this in a generic way without either disabling non-default allocators or forcing the user to spell it out.

Comment: If you just delete the 'ContainerParams...' template argument then it is fixed, maybe with some flexibility limitations, but still works for single-arg templated containers.

Comment: @thenumbernine that would prevent the use of custom allocators and associative containers, though.

Comment: Some more from the longwinded compiler template error in clang:
test8.cpp:14:42: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::vector<float,std::allocator<int>>' requested here
So it looks like the allocator itself is templated, uses the container value_type as its default template value, and then complains when the types don't match.

Comment: @thenumbernine that's the issue, yes. The allocator type gets indiscriminately forwarded through `ContainerParams` even though it does not match the element type anymore. The *Allocator* concept has a `rebind` feature for this purpose, but I don't see how to generically pick out and adjust the allocator from the additional parameters of the container.